# How can I check if a current buffer exists in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to write a function which takes action if a give buffer name already exists.  For example:

```
(if (buffer-exists "my-buffer-name")
    ; do something
 )
```

Does elisp have a function that will check the for the existence of a buffer similar to how my made up "buffer-exists" function does?

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers.html):

```
(get-buffer name)

Return the buffer named name (a string).
If there is no live buffer named name, return nil.
name may also be a buffer; if so, the value is that buffer.

(get-buffer-create name)

Return the buffer named name, or create such a buffer and return it.
A new buffer is created if there is no live buffer named name.
If name starts with a space, the new buffer does not keep undo information.
If name is a buffer instead of a string, then it is the value returned.
The value is never nil.
```

Comment: Shouldn't get-buffer be used as an argument to bufferp to verify it is indeed a buffer?

(if (bufferp (get-buffer "my-buffer-name")
;do something
)

Comment: No need to use `bufferp`. Since `get-buffer` returns either `nil` or a buffer, you can just test it directly: `(let ((b (get-buffer "foo"))) (if b ...))`

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did:

```
(when (get-buffer "*scratch*")
  (kill-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

This checks for the buffer scratch. If there's such a thing, kill it. 
If not, do nothing at all.

Comment: Use `when`, if you do not need the else clause.

Answer (score 6):

not sure about version this predicate appeared, but now Emacs has `buffer-live-p`:

```
buffer-live-p is a built-in function in `buffer.c'.

(buffer-live-p OBJECT)

Return non-nil if OBJECT is a buffer which has not been killed.
Value is nil if OBJECT is not a buffer or if it has been killed.
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You have to input a buffer-object as `OBJECT` and not a buffer name. If you pass a name of a living buffer as `OBJECT` you get the return value `nil`. Maybe, it is worth a comment though.

Comment: this make sence. May be I should create separate question for this? i just searched for `buffer-live-p` functionality and found only this approach..

Comment: This helped me out considerably since `get-buffer` will return `#<killed buffer>` rather than `nil` if the buffer once existed!

Comment: @AlexanderGriffith I could not reproduce this. After **(kill-buffer "*scratch*")** and then **(get-buffer "*scratch*")** returns nil.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit If you run it all in one script `get-buffer` will return `#<killed buffer>`. For example, try running `(let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "scratch")))
  (kill-buffer buffer)
  (cons (buffer-live-p buffer) (get-buffer buffer)))`

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to define your hypothetical function as above, this works:

```
(defun buffer-exists (bufname)   (not (eq nil (get-buffer bufname))))
```

I use this to automatically close the `*scratch*` buffer on startup, so I don't have to cycle through it in my list of buffers, as follows:

```
(defun buffer-exists (bufname) (not (eq nil (get-buffer bufname))))
(if (buffer-exists "*scratch*")  (kill-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

Comment: Note that `(eq nil <foo>)` is the same as `(null <foo>)` or `(not <foo>)`, so `(not (eq nil (get-buffer bufname)))` is `(not (not (get-buffer bufname)))`, so you can drop the double negation and just use `(get-buffer bufname)`.  At which point you can redefine `buffer-exists` as an alias for `get-buffer`.

Comment: @Stefan (nitpick) The given `buffer-exists` is not exactly the same as `get-buffer` because it will return either `t` or `nil`, but never the actual buffer.